# I need an open source php social script, minus the social features

Tags: looking-for-a-script, open-source, social-media

I need a script that can support basically only the profile part of a social site.

- Gallery
- Avatar
- Custom fields for the profile
- User activation must be authorized by an admin

Is there something that can do this?

Comment: I am looking for something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is easy with [Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal) (licensed under [GPL 2](http://drupal.org/LICENSE.txt)).

[Download](https://drupal.org/project/drupal) Drupal 7 (Recommended release) and install it. You need PHP and a database (e. g. MySQL).

Drupal comes with 3 of your 4 features out of the box:

1. Go to <kbd>Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings</kbd>.
2. Under "**Who can register accounts?**"  you can select "**Visitors, but administrator approval is required**".
3. Under "**Personalization**" you can activate "**Enable user pictures.**" to allow users to upload an avatar.
4. Now click at "**Save configuration**"
5. Then click at "**Manage fields**" (in the upper right corner)
6. There you can add fields for the user profiles.

For the gallery, there are *countless* ways to implement it. Which way you should use depends on your requirements. There are [various modules](http://drupal.org/search/site/Gallery?f[0]=drupal_core%3A103&f[1]=bs_project_sandbox%3A0&f[2]=ss_meta_type%3Amodule) that can be installed. But it's also possible (and often advisable, because it is more flexible) to "build" it by hand (all in the backend interface, no programming required).

You could create a new content type ("Image"), add an image field to it, and set the permissions so that registered users can create a new "Image" node. With the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module (one of the most powerful and popular modules of Drupal) you could create a list of all images uploaded by user, and display that list (e.g. thumbnails linked to the full image) on user profiles or on separate pages (per user).

We have an own StackExchange site for Drupal, where you could outline your specific gallery requirements and ask what would be the best way to implement it: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I bet you could customize [drupal](http://www.drupal.org/) to do this. With drupal, you could disable all of the modules that are responsible for the "content/site" part of drupal, and just keep the profile modules enabled. You might have to find a module that lets each user have their own gallery, but I bet there is one out there.

Answer (score 0):

Try [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org/) from Automattic, makers of Wordpress. It should have everything you are looking for, and is open source so it's free and you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

Several options in php:

1. [Dolphin](http://www.boonex.com/dolphin)
2. [Elgg](http://www.elgg.org/)
3. [Oxwall](http://www.oxwall.org/)
4. [Jcow](http://www.jcow.net/)
5. [Beatz](http://www.cogzidel.com/pure-volume-clone)
6. [Etano](http://www.datemill.com/)
7. [PeoplePods](http://peoplepods.net/)

   In rails: [lovdbyless](http://lovdbyless.com/)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will allow you to moderate logins, let users set their avatar or use Gravatar. This is a great tutorial on setting up custom profile fields for users in WordPress http://www.stemlegal.com/greenhouse/2012/adding-custom-fields-to-user-profiles-in-wordpress/. And there are plenty of galleries you can use, NextGen being the most popular. Here are some of the showcased WordPress websites used as social networks http://wordpress.org/showcase/tag/social-network/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend http://www.elgg.org. Some of the ones mentioned above have some issue with them, ranging from possessing a very ugly appearance, to small weird glitches in setting them up, so being too sparse and thus requiring lots of tweaking.

Thinking outside the box could lead you to BBpress!. It is forum software, but has what you indicated you want. Plus, being for forums, you are ready to socialize and interact with your users. It looks nice, and is easy to use. It also can live well with Wordpress.  The following site has some suggested plugins to add functionality:
http://www.aboutonlinetips.com/20-top-bbpress-plugins-for-building-powerful-forum/